# Sum of triangular number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Well, known triangular numbers $$1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, \cdots$$ I am looking for different methods to get the sum of those numbers. I know we can write it as below
$$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^i i\\=
\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{i(i+1)}{2}=\\
\frac 12 \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (i+i^2)=\\
\frac12 (\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6})=\\
\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}3$$ I know we that we can show it by $\mathit{mathematical} \space  \mathscr{Induction}$,   But are there more methods to show this fact? As an example a proof without a word, or something else. Thanks in advance for any hint, solution, or different ideas. Also, I  am looking for specifics about the heuristic solution.

Answer (score 5):

Using [hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity):
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k(k+1)}{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} {k +1 \choose 2}=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} {k  \choose 2}={n+2 \choose 3}$$

Answer (score 2):

There are a few "Proof Without Words" of this in Nelson's *Proof Without Words*. One goes as follows:

Consider the triangle

```
 1
 1 2
 1 2 3
 : ...
 1 2 3 ... n-1
 1 2 3 ... n-1 n
```

and its rotations

```
 1                      n
 2 1                    n-1 n-1 
 3 2 1                  n-2 n-2 n-2 
 : ...                  : ...
 n-1 n-2 ... 2 1        2 2 2 2 ... 2 2
 n  n-1 n-2 ... 2 1     1 1 1 1 ... 1 1 1
```

Summing up each entry in the three triangles we obtain:

```
n+2
n+2 n+2
n+2 n+2 n+2
: ...
n+2 n+2 n+2 ... n+2
```

Therefore $T_n (n+2) = 3\sum T_n$.

Thus $\sum T_n = \dfrac {n(n+1)(n+2)}6$.

Comment: Why do you use words then? $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I still haven't mastered the true essence of PWWs.