# Find and prove formula for $ \sum_{i=0}^{n} {i\choose i -2 }$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Find and prove formula for  $$  \sum_{i=0}^{n} {i\choose i -2 }\qquad\hbox{for all $n \in \mathbb{No}$} $$

$\mathbb{No}$ is  {0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... }

It is clear for me that for $$ i = 0.  {0\choose -2 }  = 0 $$
and for
$$ i = 1.  {1\choose -1 }  = 0 $$

but I have to find a formula that will let me simplify the sigma.

I am also not sure but I suppose that there might be connection with the sum formula

$$ \sum_{i=1}^ni^2 = \frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}$$

Should I somehow use it to bring it to the right form?
Are they any binominal formulas that I dont know and they can help me with that?

Comment: This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852108/sum-of-triangular-number/3852118#3852118

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

$${i\choose i-2}={i\choose 2} = \frac{i(i-1)}{2}$$

Comment: Does this mean that my question can be rewritten as $\sum_{i=1}^n {i\choose 2 }$ ?
and  $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i(i-1)}{2} $

Comment: @goldoner Exactly!

Comment: Thanks! I solved it at the end!